# How can I add an primary ID column for a join table with Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have created a Many to Many relationship between two objects with Spring JPA and PostgreSQL. For simplicity, let's call them Student and Classes, where a Student can have many Classes and vice-versa.

I have an Entity for both Student and Class, and set them up with a Many to Many relationship. It creates a "student_classes" join table using @JoinTable, with columns "student_id" and "class_id". However, there is no primary key column, such as an incrementing integer.

I want to remember ordering of when relationships are made when querying. I want to have a primary key ID column (incrementing) that tracks that.

How can I accomplish this with the @JoinTable annotation?

So instead of just "student_id" and "class_id" columns, there would be an "id" column as well that auto-increments by 1 each time.

Comment: Make the join table a separate entity. Call it Enrollment.

Comment: I see, but how would I specify that as a join table for JPA? Or would I just make that separate entity/table the same name as the name passed in my @JoinTable annotation?

Comment: You should not make it a join table.  It is a (weak) entity.  Give it mapped many:one relationships with both Student and Class, and give it any other properties you like, such as a timestamp.  At need, navigate from Class to Student or vice versa *via* this additional entity.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. The documentation for JoinTable indicated that its not very flexible lol. What about querying? It looks like I'd need to do a multiple queries to fetch, for example, all Classes entities for one student.

Comment: Ignore the above comment I made, resolved it in the answer below. (I can't delete or edit the above comment so I am posting here as an FYI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Nathan, you can create a separate class called `Enrollment`.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Enrollment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    Student student;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "class_id")
    Class aClass;

}
```

And,then refer them in `Student`

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    Set<Enrollment> registrations;
}
```

and, `Class`.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Class {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "aClass")
    Set<Enrollment> registrations;
}
```

Comment: I see. That makes sense. If I want the info for all classes of a student, I am wondering if there is a straightforward approach to it besides this: 1. querying for all Enrollment entities for specific student 2. going through each Enrollment entity then querying for its corresponding Class entity

Comment: Yes, you can query the particular student. And, from the student object, you can just use the getter methods. Like: students.getRegistrations() and from the registrations you can get the classes.

Comment: Oh I was overthinking it. The Enrollment has the instances of the entities via JPA, therefore I wouldn't have to query again to get the actual data. Okay, thanks - that makes sense!

Comment: Or, you can do it in single query as well using the joins. Similar to: select classes from class c join student s join enrollment e where e.student_id = studentId. This is not the correct syntax, just an idea

Comment: Good to know - I saw examples of those while searching it up as well. Will definitely be useful in the future. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I had another question that I am a bit lost on. In this example, how would I add registrations? With @JoinTable, you'd simply just do setClasses(<data>) on the Student object. However with a custom join table Entity, how would I do that same thing? Currently, I can only see that you can just make a new List of Enrollments i.e. new Enrollment(student, class) then call setRegistrations(<enrollment list>) but that seems a bit clunky.

Comment: Looks like I am getting "infinite recursion" while trying to add registrations for a Student, unless I am doing it wrong.. I have no idea.